# Titanium - know if a contact have my app installed

Tags: android, ios, titanium, contacts, acs

I use Chat ACS Titanium http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/chats/create in my app.
I've need to know if there are people of my contacts book that have my app installed (like whatsapp o viber). 
Is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all the email addresses or phone numbers or similar from the contacts book, then run a query to find all the matching users (hint: you'd use `email: { $in: [ 'all', 'the', 'emails' ] }`).

http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/users/query

Comment: Thanks Dawson, in this way with one call I can get all results :-)